# My Bitnami Django website shows the Bitnami homepage instead of mine. How to change it?

Tags: python, django, web, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I deployed a website on AWS LIGHTSAIL. I assigned an static IP to that instance and when I enter to it, it shows me the Bitnami homepage.

When I run the virtual env in the Django project (python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000) I have to put the :8000 on my static IP for my website to shows up.

What I'm doing wrong? How do I make my website appears on the default port? Thanks!

Comment: Hi! Using `manage.py` is useful when you are testing your setup. If you want to move to production, you can configure Apache to use `mod_wsgi` to serve your application. You can find a guide with the detailed process for Bitnami Django [here](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/).